# if browser window width is more than x, enclose div in new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fairly simple function I am wanting to implement into my site, where once the browser windows width is more than or equal to **x**, it will enclose `<div>` **a** inside of `<div>` **b**. (Or any other HTML element i.e: `<span>`).

I have pretty basic knowledge of JavaScript and jQuery. But, I still tried to create the script anyway (well parts of it).

This is what I have so far:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

if(windowWidth > 1919){
    $(".navbar").wrap( "<div class='center'></div>" ); // center navbar
}
```

One of the problems I am facing with this script is that it will not check the window width automatically. Rather, it will only check it once the page has been refreshed.

How would I get around this problem?

**EDIT:** I have updated my code. All is working well, except for one tiny thing.

When I go to open my `DOM Explorer` in Chrome, if the width is more than 1919px, then it will enclose the `div` in multiple other `div`s.

Something along the lines of this:

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="center">
        <div class="center">
            <div class="center">
                <!-- this will continue for ages until finally displaying the actual navbar div !-->
                <div class="navbar">
                    <!-- e.t.c. !-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I decided to update my jQuery a little bit, and now it looks like this:

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1920px)").matches) {
        $(".navbar").wrap("<div class='center'></div>");
    } else {
        var content = $(".center").contents();
        $(".center").replaceWith(content);
    }
}).trigger("resize");
```

How would I stop it from duplicating the `div` element more than once?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If your code is working fine and the only issue you have is that it does not get called automatically, then below code should solve this problem. Here, I have attached your code to a window `resize` event, and also triggered it once, so that on page load, the function is executed once automatically. After that, it gets called whenever window is resized.

I have also added an `else` clause, because I suppose you would want to unwrap the `.navbar` if the window width decreases below your selected limit. You can use this or omit as per your requirement.

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();

  if(windowWidth > 1919){
    $(".navbar").wrap( "<div class='center'></div>" ); // center navbar
  }
  else{
    $(".navbar").unwrap('.center');
  }
}).trigger("resize");//window resize
```

Comment: I'll attempt this! Thanks :)

Comment: yeah. let me know if it doesn't work, because I have simply wrapped your own code in this flow, without checking if that works or not.

Comment: worked perfectly! thanks :-) will select your answer as correct in a few minutes when it lets me

Comment: Why not simply use the `Window.matchMedia()` where it's more efficient than the `window.resize()`

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri You may be right, but as most of us are used to using `resize`, I went with that. Moreover, that was just to point out the issue in the question. We can use `setTimeout` to make `resize` (and 'scroll') handlers more efficient though. Thanks for the info :) .

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj could you please take a look at my new edit? :-) thanks

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic Please check now. I have updated the `unwrap` call.

Answer (score 2):

The `window.resize()` is inefficient in this scenario. I would recommend you to use the `window.matchmedia()` to do what ever your logic should do. I doesn't fire all the time when browser resizes, where only executes when the specific resolution is hit. Read the following documentation and you'll get an idea.

[MDN ; MatchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Sample event handler is as following.

```
var media = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1919px)");

media.addListener(function(m)}{
    if(m.matches){
      $(".navbar").wrap( "<div class='center'></div>" );
    }else{
      //Remove the wrap
    }
})
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste this? haha

Comment: yeah from my own answe! :D

Comment: think you might be able to make more sense of it so I can tailor it to my needs? :-)

Comment: I updated the logic and based on your requirement, you should have a requirement to remove the wrapped element when not in the mentioned resolution. I didn't write that, bt if you want to, will gladly help on that!

Comment: as in? should work as I use this code. Debug the code and see whether it hits on the if condition when the resolution is matched!

Comment: as in, when the page width is more than `1919px` it still won't wrap :/

Answer (score 1):

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();

if(windowWidth > 1919){
    $(".navbar").wrap( "<div class='center'></div>" ); // center navbar
}
});
```

You can use this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

The code to wrap the div element should execute once. When the page width is already greater than the required value you do not need to wrap anything as it is already wrapped.

```
var isWrapped = false;
$(window).on("resize", function(){
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

if(windowWidth > 1919 && !isWrapped){
$(".navbar").wrap( "<div class='center'></div>" ); // center navbar
isWrapped = true;
}
else{
//remove wrapping div
isWrapped = false;
}
}).trigger("resize");
```